# Cannot allocate memory when forking in Python, but there is memory

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, fork

When I run the following Thread, it spawns 5 forks. The first time I run it, it goes smooth, everything ok. But when it runs again, after the sleep(60) (while True loop), by the time the thread tries to fork() the processes, I get the following error:

**OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory**

```
_td = threading.Thread(target=updateProxies,args=())
_td.start()

def updateProxies():
    while True:
        quota = 5
        children = []
        sons = 0
        for i in range(50):
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid:
                children.append(pid)
                sons+=1
                if sons >= quota:
                    os.wait()
                    sons-=1
            else:
                 {CHILD CODE EXECUTION} #database calls, and network requests
                 os._exit(0)
        for x in children:
            os.waitpid(x,0)
        sleep(60)
```

Things I debugged:

- Already tracked if there are any defuncts left from the previous forks and there are none.
- Already monitored the server memory, and there are plenty left (at least to spawn more forks again)

My bash script to monitor the memory is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  while true
  do
  free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%\n"), $3/$2*100}'
  sleep .5
  done
```

Which marked:

```
used: 16.41%, swap: 3.86% #before the script execution
used: 21.32%, swap: 3.86% #during the 5 forks execution
used: 19.86%, swap: 3.86% #after the 5 forks ended
```

This means that the 5 forks only increased around **5%** percent of memory when they got spawned. So there is memory available. Then why I just can't spawn the forks again?